# get element by class for chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add this code into a chrome extension to alert me when a chatbox is available. Its in a div with class name shoutbox as of now it doesnt work.

```
function Detection(){
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("shoutbox")!=null){
      alert('Chat is available.')
    }
}

Detection();
```

Updated Code: the page loads and the alert dialog never appears.

```
function Detection(){
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("shoutbox").length > 0){
        alert('Chat is available.')
    }
}

window.onload = Detection;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on _it doesn't work_? You may also have more success getting answers if you accept some of the ones on your previous questions.

Comment: try this = document.getElementsByClassName("shoutbox").value != null

Comment: I haven't done extensions, but wouldn't you still need to do a window.onload, or domready of some fashion? It probably doesn't exist because it hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: The classname in the first (`"shoutbox"`) is different from the classname in the second (`"shoutboxt"`).

Comment: Maybe that chatbox is not present on the page from the beginning and is added later?

Comment: @serg oh any ideas what i could do to test or maybe you have a code solution?

Answer (score 5):

`== null` won't detect an empty array (no results). You could write

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("shoutbox").length > 0){
  alert('Chat is available.')
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I added updated code and the alert dialog doesn't appear

Comment: Check the typo Matt mentions in a comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

If chatbox is not on the page since the beginning and is added later (it is simple to check -  just view the page source), you can monitor `DOMSubtreeModified` event which would fire whenever any modification is done to the page DOM:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("shoutbox").length > 0){
        alert('Chat is available.')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("shoutbox")` returns an array of elements, and returns a blank array if it doesn't find anything.  To see if the elements exist, check the length of the array.

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("shoutbox").length > 0){
```

Comment: thanks for the input i added my updated code and the alert dialog never appears any ideas why this could be?

Comment: yes i saw that and corrected it but still have the same issue

Comment: @jennifer: Are you sure there is a div with class 'shoutbox' in the page?

Comment: looks like this `code <div class="shoutbox">
 <h2>Shoutbox</h2>
 <div class="shoutbox-content">
  <p><iframe src="/shout.php" style="width: 250px; height: 600px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></p>
 </div>
</div> `